# Error when compiling OpenFOAM-8

Tags: compiling, dns

Error occurs when I try to compile OpenFOAM-8. I type

```
./Allwmake
```

and it reports:

```
wmake DNS
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/applications/solvers/DNS'   
wmake dnsFoam        
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/applications/solvers/DNS/dnsFoam'
g++ -std=c++11 -m64 -Dlinux64 -DWM_ARCH_OPTION=64 -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32 -Wall -Wextra -Wold-style-cast -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-attributes -O3  -DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -I/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/src/randomProcesses/lnInclude -I/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude -I/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/src/meshTools/lnInclude -IlnInclude -I. -I/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude -I/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/src/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude   -fPIC -fuse-ld=bfd -Xlinker --add-needed -Xlinker --no-as-needed /home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/applications/solvers/DNS/dnsFoam/dnsFoam.o -L/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib \   
     -lrandomProcesses -lfiniteVolume -lmeshTools -lOpenFOAM -ldl  \      
     -lm -o /home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/dnsFoam/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI::Op::Init(void (*)(void const*, void*, int, MPI::Datatype const&), bool)'
/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `PMPI::Intracomm::current_op'                                   
/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `PMPI::Comm::mpi_comm_map' 
/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI::Is_initialized()'                                  
/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `PMPI::Comm::mpi_err_map'                          
/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `MPI::Op::Free()'  
/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so: undefined reference to `op_intercept'      
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/wmake/makefiles/general:140: recipe for target '/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/dnsFoam' failed    
make[2]: *** [/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/dnsFoam] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/applications/solvers/DNS/dnsFoam
/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/wmake/makefiles/apps:39: recipe for target 'dnsFoam' failed 
make[1]: *** [dnsFoam] Error 2    
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/applications/solvers/DNS'     
/home/ht45454/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/wmake/makefiles/apps:39: recipe for target 'DNS' failed    
make: *** [DNS] Error 2
```

Do I miss some essential files? What should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check https://openfoam.org/download/8-ubuntu/ .

Comment: I tried this before, not working... Resulted from weak network connection I suppose. Then I move to this [link](https://openfoam.org/download/8-source/) .